# Magento 2: How can i change the data automatically using ko.observable

Tags: magento2

I have tried to create one simple code to change the bind value click on the button.
when I load the page it's showing the message `dev` but when I click on the button its should show second but right now nothing happens when clicking on the button. is any ideas please share. I don't want to use setInterval.

HTML template file:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: getClock()"></h1>
<button type="button"
    click="action">
Click
</button>
```

JS file:

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko'
], function(Component, ko) {
    return Component.extend({
        clock: ko.observable("dev"),
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        },
        getClock: function () { 
            return this.clock;
        },
        action: function () {
            return this.clock = 'second';
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing

```
    action: function () {
        return this.clock = 'second';
    },
```

with

```
    action: function () {
        this.clock('second');
    },
```

Comment: Yes it's working. Thanks Marius ;)